# How to search inside files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am a google drive user(not a API user or developer). I want to know is there any way to search inside the file contents. I know the filenames can be searched with search bar. But i couldn't find a way to search inside files.

For example,

I have a file **Names.txt** which contains

```
Oracle
Microsoft
IBM
```

How can i get,say Microsoft, just by searching?

I got this information

```
useContentAsIndexableText   boolean     Whether to use the content as indexable text. (Default: false)
```

from

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

and nothing more helpful :p

Any idea, how to get the file content by searching?

Comment: You say you're *not* an API developer - are you trying to *become* one, or are you just trying to do this from the web UI? It's not clear whether this is a programming question or not...

Comment: If you are asking about the web UI, as @JonSkeet says, it's offtopic for SO. But I just tried it and a plain search from the web gui **does** search inside the files. Also more details about UI search capabilities here https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en&p=empty_search_ww&rd=1

Comment: Thanks for Interest of both of you.I found my answer. You are right i was trying it from web UI. And it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, i found one way to sort the files which contains the text from the link below.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en&ref_topic=2463645

That is by including the search term in in double quotes.

So if i search with "Microsoft". Then only files that contains Microsoft will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need some kind of UI to do a full-text content search in your GDrive. There is several tools to do it.

First, you can do it on your desktop with [DTSearch](https://dtsearch.com/) or [MetaSearch](https://www.meta.sc/beta/)
Secondly, you can use cloud based solution [Findo](https://findo.com/)

None of solutions fit me properly, so I decided to write my own cloud based document search engine - [Ambar](https://ambar.cloud). As for now it's supports only Dropbox. But you can give it a try as well with manual uploads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "" in the search box, neverthless if you have a lot of pdfs, convert it to doc format, this way you'll be able to look up information in books. 
**Though I would recommend to hold your pdf files in your computer and analyze it with a pdf reader(For example PDF-XChange Viewer)**